# $C$ is convex and norm closed $\implies C$ is weakly closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces, weak-topology

> **Proposition** $:$ Let $C$ be a convex and norm closed subset of a Banach space $V.$ Then $C$ is weakly closed.
>
> *Proof* $:$ Let, $x_0 \notin C.$ Then  by Hahn-Banach theorem there exists $f \in V^{\ast}, \alpha \in \mathbb R$ such that $$f(x_0) \lt \alpha \lt f(x)$$ for all $x \in C.$ Let $$U : = \{x \in V\ |\ f(x) \lt \alpha \}.$$ Then $U$ is $\color{blue}{\text{weakly open}}$ and $U \cap C = \varnothing.$ This shows that $C^{\complement}$ is weakly open and hence $C$ is weakly closed. $\square$

In the above proof I failed to understand why $U$ is weakly open. Instead what I know is that the set $W = \{x \in V\ |\ |f(x)| \lt \alpha \}$ is weakly open. Is there any way to say from this stage that $U$ is also weakly open?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc$:$ Another small question which I can't refrain from asking is $:$ Why do we need $V$ to be Banach? The version of Hahn-Banach separation theorem used in the proof is valid for any locally convex topological vector space and since any normed linear space is locally convex it seems to me that the proposition is true for any arbitrary normed linear spaces. Am I right?

Comment: @Anne Bauval$:$ Another small question which I can't refrain from asking is $:$ Why do we need $V$ to be Banach? The version of Hahn-Banach separation theorem used in the proof is valid for any locally convex topological vector space and since any normed linear space is locally convex it seems to me that the proposition is true for arbitrary normed linear spaces. Am I right?

Comment: It holds in any normed linear space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weak topology is, by definition, the weakest topology such that all bounded linear functionals on $V$ are continuous. Therefore $f$ is continuous with respect to that topology. Observe that
$$U=\{x\in V\,:\, ({\rm Re}\, f)(x)<\alpha\}=f^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha)\times \mathbb{R})$$ Therefore $U$ is open in the weak topology.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145437/discussion-on-answer-by-ryszard-szwarc-c-is-convex-and-norm-closed-implies-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @XanderHenderson$:$ Why did you move the comments to chat? If you closely look at the comments between me and the answerer you will find that they are very much relevant to the clarification or improvement of the proof which continued till the proof became clear as crystal. So I don't find it necessary to move the comments to chat and as it is not supported by latex the chat needs decoding the latex program to make a person enable to read the content there and hence it is not much reading friendly. I wouldn't personally prefer misusing extravagant display of power everywhere nonsensically.